# Почему Chrome не видит position:relative?

Tags: html, css, css3

Скриншот работы блока в Firefox : http://joxi.ru/Dr83lvBTdXVDA6 
А вот так в Chrome : http://joxi.ru/823LJbBigWEXAO

 
Это табличная верстка, вот код :

```
<tbody class="review-list-item ">
  <tr class="review-list-item-row metro-feedback-properties ">
    <td class="feedback-number">{$item.mall}</td>
    <td class="date">{$item.created_formated.full}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
tbody {
    position: relative;
    height: 105px;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}
.second-text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }
```

Текст, который в хроме ушел вверх - это .second-text. У него есть position:absolute и так впечатление, что хром не понимает position:relative у tbody.  
Есть идеи как лечить?
Спасибо

Comment: возможно, упущено свойство bottom: 0 или какое-то аналогичное

Comment: @lexxl Там же есть top:50px

Comment: ну я имею ввиду, что надо поэкспериментировать с этими свойствами. а лучше выложить более полный код, чтобы проблему можно было воспроизвести у себя. а вообще, надо проверить через разработчик хрома, какой параметр у position проставлен по факту

Comment: Не вижу класс `.second-text` в вашей html разметке. Скорее всего у  `.second-text` родительский элемент не `tbody`, поэтому он позиционировался относительно другого родителя.

Comment: @stackanon Не скриншоты клацнули?